# C#, WPF Multiple request from a single event

Tags: c#, wpf

Need your help to implement a particular logic. I have a customer search page where while searching customer multiple hosted controls get loaded independently. Once the search completed we can call close functionality. This close functionality unload all the hosted controls. 
Now I have a requirement to search a customer with external application where let say I have 3 customer button "Customer1", "Customer2" and "Customer3". As per the requirement when I click on button "Customer1" it should search "Customer1" and load all hosted controls as same as manual search. but when I click button "Customer2" it should first unload the "Customer1"  and unload all hosted controls associated with that. After that it should load "Customer2" and load all hosted controls. 
I am able to successfully Unload the "customer1" but not able to achieve the both Unloading and then Loading the "Customer2" with a single button click. 
I used backgroundworker thread to achieve it. Here main thread completing the Unloading and after a few second of Sleep background worker thread is launching the search which is loading all the hosted controls again. This is working intermittently. Can you suggest any other way to achieve this.

Comment: You need to *show your code*.  ALWAYS **show your code**.

Comment: Read this: [ask]

Comment: MVVM and a single collection with data Template ??

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code not much help can be provided other than recommending practices based on your description. The problem statement you provide is an example of where a [Mediator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) is used.

You need separate handler that understands how to talk to the other objects. That object then listens to the event and publishes it appropriately. In your case, you could even have the mediator handle the unloading (or tell the object itself to unload).